# ¿Cómo cambiar el idioma a otro html en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Tengo un archivo `index.html` que puedo cambiar de **español a ingles** con estas tres funciones:

```
function setLanguage(){
 var stag = document.createElement("script");
 stag.type = 'text/javascript';
 stag.src = "lang/"+_lang+"_.js";
 document.querySelector("head").appendChild(stag); 
 stag.onload = function (){
  afterLoad();
 }
}

function afterLoad(){
 var lan = window[_lang+"_"];

 for (var key in lan) {
  var ar = document.getElementsByClassName(key);

  for (var i = 0; i < ar.length; i++) {
    ar[i].innerHTML=lan[key];
  }
 }
}

function alt_lang(){
 var i = document.getElementById("lang_ico");
 if(_lang == "en"){
    _lang = "es";
    i.innerHTML="EN";
 } else {
    _lang = "en";
    i.innerHTML="ES";
 }
 setLanguage();
}
```

Mis carpetas son estas:

----lang

```
   ----en_.js

   ----es_.js
```

----pages

```
   ----lang

       ----en_.js
       ----es_.js

   ----aplicaciones_moviles.html
   ----desarrollo_de_software.html
   ----inteligencia_de_negocios.html
   ----outsourcing_y_capacitaciones.html
```

----index.html

pero los `index` que están dentro de la carpeta `pages` no se traducen.

Me podrían ayudar por favor.

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so], te invito a hacer el [tour] podras ganar algunas medallas y de paso saber como funcionamos!

Comment: lo que debe pasar es que al cambiar la pagina no encuentra los archivos es_ y en_ verifica si la consola te da ese errpr4

Comment: Hola, Te recomiendo que uses el cambio de idioma de otra manera, porque si no te afectara en tu SEO

Comment: @JackNavaRow Gracias por responder, si me da un error de 403 y no le traduce